Intel 386 transistor level schematics
Hi there I wanted to know where I can find the transistor level schematics of the intel 386 for a project. Thanks.

I doubt you'll find anything like that which is complete.  But do have a look at Ken Shirriff's reverse engineering 386 project, which is very interesting indeed.

The intel 836 is so complicated (there are billions of transistors) that you will not find any transister level schematics. But you can find a higher level (the architecture) for it here

You wish to find a transistor level schematics for a 370,000 transistor processor.  Why?  It would be neaningless.  Odds are it was designed with VHDL or equivalent, so it does not exist.  Aside from being propriety.

@SnappyRiffs The 386 absolutely does not have billions of transistors. Hundreds of thousands is a better approximation. Not sure where stainlesssteelrat got their 370,000 figure from, but that sounds a lot more believable to me. According to ourworldindata, transistor counts seem to have only passed 1 billion in 2006, about 20 years later than the 386.

thanks @Hearth for the mistake fix

also the ourworldindata, only has upto 2020

@SnappyRiffs That doesn't really matter when we're talking about the numbers from the 80s through 2006.

Regarding transistor count, Ken Shirriff (who has been staring at the die photos) says "The 386 processor (1985) was Intel's most complex processor at the time, with 285,000 transistors." here; he says the Pentium has 3.3m here.
